# Как из одного телеграм бота переслать сообщение в другой бот?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть один бот, который собирает данные у пользователя и потом выводит в одно сообщение.
Дальше бот должен переслать сообщение другому боту, чтоб тот вывел его в групповой чат.
Получили id второго бота, функция некорректно работает, пишет, что чат не найден.
Так вот, как переслать от одного бота сообщение другому?

Comment: Добавьте пример неработающего кода.

Comment: Как вариант, пересылать напрямую между ботами, например, через rest. Т. е. api телеграма для этого вообще не использовать.

Answer (score 1):

**Никак**. Это [запрещено](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots) API телеграма, так как боты *общаясь* могут застрять в бесконечном цикле.

> Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?
>   Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.